# PHP Code Example for Adding Steps, Activities to an Existing Automation?

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, php, automation

I'm hoping that someone might be able to share a PHP example for updating an existing automation with an additional Step and an activity associated with that step. The single example (in .Net) for updating an Automation that is shown in the existing documentation isn't very helpful in this respect.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api/#Update_an_Existing_Automation

Additionally, are there any recommendations (or warnings) around the max number of individual steps (and activities performed within a step) that a single automation should include?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: I wish there was a way to do this.